# how to change alphabetic order to descending order in drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I have a accordion menu in left side and the menu list come as alphabet order but i want newest come first. how can i change the sorting of that list.
[image]

Comment: How you've added accordion to menu?

Comment: i have create the menu first named Event and then create the content under this menu like Abc, New Event and all. In the accordion menu configuration change the menu source to event and choose the position left sidebar

Answer (score 1):

Drupal menu items are manually ordered. You can drag and drop into the correct order here: /admin/structure/menu/manage/navigation

Comment: i am not talking about admin menu, i need to sort the accordion menu list according to the descending order